# Android: Grouping audio and video files

Tags: android, database, image, audio, grouping

I am newish to Android, so please be patient with me! I am building an application in which I need to be able to allow users to record audio and take photographs in order to add entries to the app - entries will consist of multiple audio files and a single image. I need to be able to allow the user to select an entry so that they will be able to view the image and play the audio files.

What would the best way to go about this be? Should I look into storing the image and audio related to that image in a database, or is there a better way of doing this? Any advice/resources would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the audio and photos to sd-card as it is designed to save larger files. But if you want to group these audios and images, you can use database for it. Create a simple table which holds entry_id(Group id) with type(Audio,image), name and their file_path on sd-card. In this way you can keep track of your audio and images which are grouped to-gether.